# QT retrieve custom widget from layout

Tags: c++, qt, c++17, qt5, getter-setter

I have a scroll area with a layout that has 8 of the same custom widgets that have been added to it. This custom widget has a getter function that will return a value. My question is how to get back that original custom widget so I can call the getter function to retrieve the data it stores?

I have added the custom widget to the layout this way:

```cpp
for (int var = 0; var < 9; ++var) {
    calcRow *CalcWidget = new calcRow(this, &js, KeyList, SizeList);
    connect(CalcWidget, &calcRow::testSignal, this, &MainWindow::getRowData);

    ui->scrollArea_layout->layout()->addWidget(CalcWidget);
}
```

Where I am stuck:

```cpp
void MainWindow::getRowData()
{
    for (int i = 0;i < ui->scrollArea_layout->layout()->count() ;++i ) {
        QWidget *row = ui->scrollArea_layout->layout()->itemAt(i)->widget();

        if(row != NULL)
        {
            std::cout << row->"SOMETHING TO GET CALCROW WIDGET"  <<std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use qobject_cast or dynamic_cast to cast the *row pointer to the type of object it is and call your getter directly

Comment: @drescherjm Thank you. That worked! I didn't know that was a thing.

Comment: Also, if you know for sure the widget is the type you want, you can use static_cast and save yourself a lot of performance.

Comment: @JanHošek You are right! that does help! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it's not the best structure for your code, any layout change might break your implementation. For example this solution will not work if you will have multiple `calcRow` widgets.

To make it better, you can pass required parameters which you want use inside `getRowData` as a parameters of `testSignal` signal.

Or just simplify it even more with lambda:

```
for (int var = 0; var < 9; ++var) {
    calcRow* CalcWidget = new calcRow(this, &js, KeyList, SizeList);
    connect(CalcWidget, &calcRow::testSignal, [CalcWidget]() 
        {
        std::cout << CalcWidget->"SOMETHING TO GET CALCROW WIDGET" << std::endl;
        });

    ui->scrollArea_layout->layout()->addWidget(CalcWidget);
}
```

Comment: I like this idea and most times I think that is a great way to do it, but for the overall program, I need to get the data from each of the custom widgets every time a change is made to any of them. That is why I am sending it through a loop instead of using a lambda function like that.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that will find this in the future, the comments helped a bunch and I ended up using `static_cast`. My final code looks like this:

```
void MainWindow::getRowData()
{
    for (int i = 0;i < ui->scrollArea_layout->layout()->count() ;++i ) {
        QWidget *row = ui->scrollArea_layout->layout()->itemAt(i)->widget();

        calcRow *rowConverted = static_cast<calcRow*>(row);

        if(row != NULL)
        {
            std::cout << rowConverted ->getData()  <<std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```